# Terraform error configuring AWS provider backend issue

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

i've had this issue in terraform with backend configuration. I am getting this error when running Terraform plan.

Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.
│
│ Please see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│
│ Error: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request send failed, Get "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: i/o timeout

```
 with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].west,
```

│    on providers.tf line 5, in provider "aws":
│    5: provider "aws" {
│
╵

Here is the code, there are no google pages to help with this error. I will appreciate any help and I'm forever grateful thanks

```
terraform {
  `enter code here`backend "remote" {
organization = "Gnome2"

workspaces {
  name = "terraform-begin"
}
```

}

```
required_providers {
aws = {
  source  = "hashicorp/aws"
  version = "4.8.0"
}
```

}
}

```
 provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  }

  provider "aws" {
  alias  = "west"
  region = "us-west-1"
  }
  module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  providers = {
  aws = aws.west
```

}

```
  name = "my-vpc"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  azs             = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
  private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24", "10.0.103.0/24"]

  enable_nat_gateway = true
  enable_vpn_gateway = true

  tags = {
      Terraform   = "true"
      Environment = "dev"
 }
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you use your AWS CLI to connect to your AWS account? like listing your AWS s3 buckets? based on the error I think you didn't configure your AWS by doing `aws configure` on your CLI. which will require you to have an access key id and secret for the setup.

Answer (score 4):

You must configure AWS' credentials in the `Terraform Cloud`. In the `Terraform Cloud` platform, go to `Settings -> Variable Sets -> Create Variable Set`, put some "name", check  "Apply to all workspaces in this organization" and click on buttom "Add Variable". Select "Environment variable" option, and inform the  `key=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `value="Access key ID"`. The "Acces key ID" is the ID from AWS credential(IAM). Check the "sensitive" checkbox and click on buttom "Add Variable". So, retry this process to add a new `Environment variable` with the `key/value` pair `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY/Secret access key of AWS credential`. Finally, click on buttom "Create variable set". Retry the `terraform plan` command. See more in https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/aws-get-started/aws-remote#set-workspace-variables

Answer (score 2):

There is a safe way to authenticate Terraform Cloud with AWS, which avoids secrets entirely:

1. Create an IAM identity provider
2. Create an IAM role which trusts that provider
3. Add two environment variables to Terraform Cloud

### 1. Create an IAM identity provider:

[image]

### 2. Create an IAM role which trusts that provider:

- The role includes a trust relationship that looks like this.  Replace `my-tfc-org` with the name of your organization in Terraform, and `<aws-account-id>` with your aws account number.
- Also attach to the role all the permissions your terraform needs.

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
         "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:oidc-provider/app.terraform.io"
       },
       "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
       "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
            "app.terraform.io:aud": "aws.workload.identity"
         },
         "StringLike": {
            "app.terraform.io:sub": "organization:my-tfc-org:project:*:workspace:*:run_phase:*"
         }
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

### 3. Add two environment variables to Terraform Cloud:

The value of TFC_AWS_RUN_ROLE_ARN points to the role you created above:

[image: These can be in the clear.]

This answer is a reproduction of the AWS documention here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/simplify-and-secure-terraform-workflows-on-aws-with-dynamic-provider-credentials/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

To resolve it first add the backend configuration setting like the following example:

```
  backend "remote" {
    hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "org-example"

    workspaces {
      name = "my-aws-app"
    }
  }
```

Then in the terminal do:
`terraform init -reconfigure`

Then go to Terraform Cloud, select your workspace, in my example my-aws-app and then under Variables/Workspace variables select add variables and add `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` making sure you choose environment variable when selecting it on the top.

Then you can go back to the terminal and do

`terraform plan`

And it should work fine now.